# Formatting correspondence within Latex

Tags: math-mode, equations

I'm trying to emulate the following types of formatting within a math environment:

[p.709 Dummit and Foote, proposition 38(3)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPJiZ.png)

[image]

I've looked around and managed to do the following:

```
 \[     
     \left\{ H | H\leqslant G \right\}
     \leftrightarrow
     \left\{\text{\shortstack[c]{\\\\equivalence relations $\sim_L$\\ on
     $G$ satisfying\\ property  \ref{eq:leftEquiv}}}\right\}
\]
```

which gives:

[latex output of above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrICh.png)

[image]

I'm a bit lost on how to make the text align in the middle of the curly braces, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Your sample code is incomplete, it that it has a lot of undefined macros.  Please edit your question to provide a small but functional minimum working example that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: thank you for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

[image]

I arrived at the width of the `\parbox` by trial and error.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand{\eqrel}{\sim_{\mkern-1.5mu L}} % macro for "equivalence relation[s]"

\begin{document}

\[     
     \left\{\, H \mid H\leqslant G \,\right\}
     \leftrightarrow
     \left\{
        \parbox{4.5cm}{\centering 
           equivalence relations $\eqrel$ 
           on~$G$ satisfying property 4.1}
     \right\}
\] 

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you! This was what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `tabular` for the textual inset.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\{H \mid H\le G\}
\;
\begin{gathered}
\overset{e}{\longrightarrow} \\[-2ex]
\underset{c}{\longleftarrow}
\end{gathered}
\;
\left\{
  \begin{tabular}{@{} c @{}}
  equivalence relations $\sim_L$ \\
  on $G$ satisfying \\
  property \ref{eq:leftEquiv}
  \end{tabular}
\right\}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't need the labeled arrows, replace the whole `\;...\;` with `\longleftrightarrow`

[image]

Comment: thank  you! The labelled arrow's were something I was looking for too!